# Why is American Pie called American Pie?

Tags: title, american-pie

I always wondered why a sexual comedy film would be called *American Pie*. I mean what is the significance of "Pie" in the title?

Comment: Did you watch the original movie there is a significant moment with an actual american pie. And hence the name.

Comment: `I always wonder...` Have you ever watched the film? There are numerous references to an actual pie there.

Comment: @defaultlocale Yup i know the pie scene but its for a minute and doesn't play a big part in the story.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I beg to differ. If you had to choose one scene that describes the whole movie that would be it. It's the most famous scene in the movie for a reason.

Comment: @SystemDown i will chose that Nadia scene.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma, I wouldn't say the first movie is all about the pie scene. What I would say is that the first movie is all about losing your virginity, which is a very *American* norm to want to do as soon as you can. The writer uses "American Pie" as sort of a metaphor, relating "pie" to your first sexual experience. When you read the title don't think about a delicious desert. Think sexual innuendo.

Comment: Well, I would imagine due to the relatively explicit scene involving Jason Biggs' character and the baked good... isn't it romantic? :-P

Comment: The word "pie" has been used as a euphemism for *that* part of the female anatomy, if you get my drift.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is answered pretty well on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_%28film%29). Specifically, the last sentence in the quote below.

> The title is borrowed from the folk song of the same name and refers to a scene in the film, in which the lead character is caught masturbating with a pie after being told that third base feels like "warm apple pie". It's also been stated by writer Adam Herz that the title also refers to the quest of losing your virginity in high school, which is as "American as apple pie."

The writer is using "pie" as a metaphor for your first sexual experience. When you read the title "American Pie," don't think of it as a delicious desert, but rather as a sexual innuendo.